# Kinect v2 Control Basics, Kinect Region

Tags: wpf, kinect-v2

In Kinect V2, control basics wpf sample, how do you disengage hand cursor through code.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I am using the control basics wpf  sample code provided in kinect SDK browser v2.0